# Creating function that makes a dictionary from a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The goal -> For each word in the text except the last one, a key should appear in the resulting dictionary, and the corresponding value should be a list of every word that occurs immediately after the key word in the text. Repeated words should have multiple values:
example:

```
fun(["ONE", "two", "one", "three"]) == 
            {"one": ["two", "three"],"two": ["one] })
```

what I have so far:

```
def build_predictions(words: list) -> dict:
  dictionary = {}
  for word in words:
    if word.index() != words.len():
      if word not in dictionary:
        dictionary.update({word : words(words.index(word)+1)})
      else:
        dictionary[word] = dictionary[word] + [words(words.index(word)+1)]
```

Im getting an EOF error ;[   -> not sure if this is right anyways.

Comment: The task is clear, however, it would be nice if you provide an expected output given a text sample.

Comment: What's the exact traceback? Nothing in this code appears to access a file, so if the problem is with the script itself, it occurs somewhere *before* your definition. (Look for an unclosed quote somewhere; unclosed parentheses or the like are also a possibility, but usually trigger a more specific error before the parser reaches the end of the file.)

Comment: Your code has compiler errors in python. `words.len()` isn't python (do you mean `len(words)`?). You want to return a `dict` but your method does not return anything... 
And most important: `EOF` means EndOfFile, thus, the part that is causing the error is missing in your code example.

Comment: In other words: Please create a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) such that we can help. 
Input data example, relevant(!) code sections, expected outcome. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can't give you an EOF error, since you don't do any file reading in the code you've shown. Since you haven't shown any of that code, I can't help you with the EOF error. However, there are a bunch of things wrong with your approach to make your dictionary of predictions:

1. `word.index()` is not a thing. If you want the index of `word` in `words`, iterate using `for index, word in enumerate(words)`
2. `words.len()` is not a thing. You can get the length of `words` by `len(words)`
3. The current word's index is never equal to the length of the list, since list indices start at `0` and go to `len(lst) - 1`. Your `if` condition should have been `if index < len(words) - 1`
   1 .You don't need to do this check at all if you simply change your loop to `for word in words[:-1]`, which will skip the last word.
4. `if word not in dictionary`, you want to *create a new list* that contains the next word.
5. If word *is* in `dictionary`, you want to *append* that word to the list instead of creating a new list by concatenating the two.
6. You need to *return* `dictionary` from your function.

Incorporating all these suggestions, your code would look like so:

```
def build_predictions(words: list) -> dict:
    dictionary = {}
    for index, word in enumerate(words[:-1]):
        next_word = words[index + 1]
        if word not in dictionary:
            dictionary[word] = [next_word]
        else:
            dictionary[word].append(next_word)
    return dictionary
```

---

Now, if you only want unique words, you can just create a dictionary containing *sets* instead of lists. That way, when you `.add()` to the set, it won't have any effect if the set already contains the word you want to add.

```
def build_predictions(words: list) -> dict:
    dictionary = {}
    for index, word in enumerate(words[:-1]):
        next_word = words[index + 1]
        if word not in dictionary:
            dictionary[word] = {next_word}     # Creates a set containing next_word
        else:
            dictionary[word].add(next_word)
    return dictionary
```

At the end of this, if you want to convert the sets back to lists, it's easy enough to do so. Instead of `return dictionary`, do:

```
    return {k: list(v) for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

---

We can remove the need to check if `word in dictionary` by using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

We can zip two slices of the list of words: one that goes from the start to the second-to-last item, and one that goes from the second item to the last item. Iterating over the `zip` of the two slices will give us the current word and the next word in each iteration.

Then, we can just collect these in a `defaultdict(list)` or a `defaultdict(set)`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def build_predictions(words: list) -> dict:
    predictions = defaultdict(list)
    # or        = defaultdict(set)
    for word, next_word in zip(words[:-1], words[1:]):
        predictions[word].append(next_word)
        # or             .add(next_word)

    return predictions
    # or   {k: list(v) for k, v in predictions.items()}
```

---

Comment: Don't do the OP's homework for them.

Comment: Plus, this is wrong, it'll keep just the last word that occurred after a word, not the list of all such words.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add part about repeated words. Edited in question -> repeated words shouldn't create new key, but add new value to repeated words key.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it should help a lot!

Comment: @markgiz [Glad this helped.](/help/someone-answers) Repeated words _wouldn't_ create a new key anyway.  If you want to ignore case, as you've shown in your expected input, you can just do `word = word.lower()` and `next_word = next_word.lower()` as soon as those are defined

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use index because it return only the index of the first occurence. This way it should work better

```
  for i in range(len(words)-1):
    word = world[i]
```